# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-emr

I have an AWS EMR cluster and all the steps are failing with the error:
'''

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

'''

Python and pip versions:

'''

```
python --version
Python 3.7.10

pip --version
pip 20.2.2 from /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

'''

Here's my requirements.txt file:
'''

```
aiobotocore==1.2.1
aiohttp==3.7.3
aioitertools==0.7.1
astroid==2.5
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==20.3.0
avro-python3
avro-validator==1.0.9
aws-encryption-sdk==2.0.0
aws-encryption-sdk-cli==2.1.0
aws-logging-handlers==2.0.5
base64io==1.0.3
boto3==1.16.34
botocore==1.19.63
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==3.0.4
configparser==5.0.1
cryptography==3.3.1
cycler==0.10.0
datacompy==0.7.1
DateTime==4.3
deap==1.3.1
decorator==4.4.2
elasticsearch==7.10.1
fsspec==0.8.5
idna==3.1
importlib-metadata==3.4.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
isort==5.7.0
jmespath==0.10.0
joblib==1.0.1
kiwisolver==1.2.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.5.2
matplotlib==3.3.3
mccabe==0.6.1
multidict==5.1.0
networkx==2.5
numpy==1.19.4
packaging==20.9
pandas==1.1.5
patsy==0.5.1
Pillow==8.1.0
pluggy==0.13.1
psycopg2==2.8.6
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
py==1.10.0
pyarrow==0.17.1
pycparser==2.20
pylint==2.6.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==6.2.2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
regex==2020.7.14
s3-concat==0.2.1
s3fs==0.5.1
s3transfer==0.3.4
scikit-learn==0.23.2
scikit-posthocs==0.6.6
scipy==1.5.4
seaborn==0.11.0
six==1.15.0
sklearn-deap2==0.2.2
sparkmeasure==0.14.0
statsmodels==0.9.0
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
toml==0.10.2
typed-ast==1.4.2
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.26.3
wrapt==1.12.1
xlrd==1.2.0
xmltodict==0.12.0
yarl==1.6.3
zipp==3.4.0
zope.interface==5.2.0
tsfresh==0.18.0
apache-sedona==1.0.1
py4j==0.10.9
shapely==1.7.1
pyspark==3.0.3
numba==0.53.1
```

'''
This is the command to install the packages:
'''

```
sudo pip-3.7 --default-timeout=60 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

'''

Below is the output from "pip list"

'''

```
Package                    Version
-------------------------- ---------
aiobotocore                1.2.1
aiohttp                    3.7.3
aioitertools               0.7.1
apache-sedona              1.0.1
astroid                    2.5
async-timeout              3.0.1
attrs                      20.3.0
avro-python3               1.10.2
avro-validator             1.0.9
aws-cfn-bootstrap          2.0
aws-encryption-sdk         2.0.0
aws-encryption-sdk-cli     2.1.0
aws-logging-handlers       2.0.5
base64io                   1.0.3
beautifulsoup4             4.9.3
boto                       2.49.0
boto3                      1.24.20
botocore                   1.19.52
certifi                    2020.12.5
cffi                       1.14.5
chardet                    3.0.4
charset-normalizer         2.1.0
click                      8.0.3
cloudpickle                2.1.0
configparser               5.0.1
cryptography               3.3.1
cycler                     0.10.0
dask                       2022.2.0
datacompy                  0.7.1
DateTime                   4.3
deap                       1.3.1
decorator                  4.4.2
distributed                2022.2.0
docutils                   0.14
elasticsearch              7.10.1
fonttools                  4.33.3
fsspec                     0.8.5
HeapDict                   1.0.1
idna                       3.1
importlib-metadata         3.4.0
iniconfig                  1.1.1
isort                      5.7.0
Jinja2                     3.1.2
jmespath                   0.10.0
joblib                     1.0.1
kiwisolver                 1.2.0
lazy-object-proxy          1.5.2
llvmlite                   0.38.1
locket                     1.0.0
lockfile                   0.11.0
lxml                       4.6.3
MarkupSafe                 2.1.1
matplotlib                 3.5.2
matrixprofile              1.1.10
mccabe                     0.6.1
msgpack                    1.0.4
multidict                  5.1.0
mysqlclient                1.4.2
networkx                   2.5
nltk                       3.6.5
nose                       1.3.4
numba                      0.53.1
numpy                      1.19.4
packaging                  20.9
pandas                     1.1.5
partd                      1.2.0
patsy                      0.5.1
Pillow                     8.1.0
pip                        20.2.2
pluggy                     0.13.1
protobuf                   3.11.2
psutil                     5.9.1
psycopg2                   2.8.6
psycopg2-binary            2.8.6
py                         1.10.0
py-dateutil                2.2
py4j                       0.10.9
pycparser                  2.20
pylint                     2.6.0
pyparsing                  2.4.7
pyspark                    3.0.3
pystache                   0.5.4
pytest                     6.2.2
python-daemon              2.2.3
python-dateutil            2.8.1
python37-sagemaker-pyspark 1.4.1
pytz                       2021.1
PyYAML                     5.4.1
regex                      2020.7.14
requests                   2.28.1
s3-concat                  0.2.1
s3fs                       0.5.1
s3transfer                 0.3.4
scikit-learn               0.23.2
scikit-posthocs            0.6.6
scipy                      1.5.4
seaborn                    0.11.0
setuptools                 49.1.3
Shapely                    1.8.2
simplejson                 3.2.0
six                        1.15.0
sklearn-deap2              0.2.2
sortedcontainers           2.4.0
sparkmeasure               0.14.0
statsmodels                0.9.0
stumpy                     1.11.1
tblib                      1.7.0
threadpoolctl              2.1.0
toml                       0.10.2
toolz                      0.11.2
tornado                    6.1
tqdm                       4.62.3
tsfresh                    0.18.0
typed-ast                  1.4.2
typing-extensions          3.7.4.3
urllib3                    1.26.3
windmill                   1.6
wrapt                      1.12.1
xlrd                       1.2.0
xmltodict                  0.12.0
yarl                       1.6.3
zict                       2.2.0
zipp                       3.4.0
zope.interface             5.2.0
```

'''

From the above pip list output, boto3 is installed. Still the steps are failing.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

if u are using linux try:

```
$ pip3 install boto3
```

make sure to rerun without sudo

Comment: Got an error "aiobotocore 1.2.1 requires botocore<1.19.53,>=1.19.52, but you'll have botocore 1.27.20 which is incompatible.". How to know which packages versions are compatible?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).